# Cached files (css, js) on the browser (Chrome) just contain html

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

I have a React js web application, and everything work well.
I cached the css and js files on the browser at the first time (will expire in 5 days).

[image]

But when I revisit the website after ~1 day, the page is empty. The cached files are loaded wrong, just contains html content (same as the page is connected).

[image]

If I refresh the caches (Ctrl + F5), the files are loaded with right content, but after ~1 day, that issue will be happened again.

So what is the wrong thing? Or it is the bug of Google Chrome (version 78)? (The bundle files are static, I don't have any deployments in this time.)

Updated: is this related to this issue: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/offline.html#offline?

Comment: Is this happening on other browsers like safari as well? That could rule out if it’s chrome specific or not.

Comment: @Gautam I'm testing on Firefox